# Remove or reset high specificity rule from a vendor controlled stylesheet

Tags: css

I'm working on some CSS in a CMS that forces some initial styles. I'm not able to remove or modify this style sheet. One line from the CMS' stylesheet is

```
a:visited {
    color: purple;
}
```

I've defined several classes in my own stylesheet that set the color for text:

```
.foo {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

`.foo` sets the color properly for most text, including unvisited links. However, since the `a:visited` rule has higher specificity, any visited links show up as purple.

What can I do to reset or remove this visited link rule?

---

I want to avoid adding more specific selectors to my stylesheet - this is just compounding the issue of selectors that are too specific:

```
foo, a.foo {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white
}
```

I tried setting the visited link color back to its initial value:

```
a:visited {
    color: initial
}
```

However, *that* rule has higher specificity than `.foo`. My text shows up as the browser's default black instead of the desired white color.

Comment: `I want to avoid adding more specific selectors to my stylesheet` --> it's like you want something and you don't want to do

Answer (score 0):

It is generally considered a bit of a hack, but if you don't want to use more specific selectors, use `!important` for the desired selector, and it will override the vendor stylesheet.

```
.foo {
    background-color: blue !important;
    color: white;
}
```

My personal preference is to use different styles of link for the different sections of the page, so for example a menu link, a link in the main section, and a link in the footer, will all be styled differently.